# How can I make SimpleWelcome/ROSA Launcher Plasmoid appear on top of other windows?

Tags: kde, plasma

[image]

When I start the launcher, it appears behind other windows, just like a general plasmoid.
Can I put it on the top?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**It seems that...**

Tested with the Rosa-laucher 2.0.0, Raring, KDE 4.10.5

It seems that the problem is the window focus.

KDE System Settings > Window Behavior > Focus tab.

[image]

If the focus is 'under mouse' then the Rosa-launcher appears on the top - at here

Comment: I'm sorry... This workaround fixed the issue, but it badly changes the window focus, in way I haven't get used to. I can't work between applications in peace, when "Focus Under Mouse" is chosen. I prefer to leave it at the default value. Please let me know if there is another workaround. Thanks!